# Is alternating current a wave like a sound wave?

Tags: waves, electric-circuits, electric-current, acoustics

Is alternating current also a wave like sound waves? And why?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking unfortunately - alternating current and sound waves are two different concepts, and I can't tell what makes you think they are similar and/or what kind of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The time dependent voltage (or current) of a simple alternating current and the time dependent amplitude of a single tone sound wave can both be described by the same mathematical expression:

$$A(t) = A_0\sin (\omega t)$$

However, physically they are completely different - an alternating current is an oscillating electric field whereas a sound wave is an oscillating longitudinal pressure wave.

Answer (score 2):

No, oscillations are not the same as waves. By *wave* we understand oscillatory behavior *both in time and space*$^1$, while the current in a wire is changing only in time, but nearly simultaneously in phase everywhere. This however would not be the case in a long transmission line, such as those
passing under the Atlantic - see [Telegrapher's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations).

---

$^1$ For pedagogical reasons I omit here solitons, shock waves, etc., which are non-oscillatory.

Comment: So by your definition a standing wave, which changes with time but is in phase everywhere, is not actually a wave and should perhaps be called a standing oscillation instead ?